# Magento 2 - category image link

Tags: magento2, php, html, administration

Is there a way to create a linkable category image which is uploaded on Category --> General information --> Image?

One way i could think of is to create a static block with an linkable image inside it and asign that block to a specific category. But for ease of administrative purpouses i would like to create an input where administrator could paste a link and category image becomes linkable in the frontend.

For example:

[image]

Comment: How are you looking to utilize this? Do you just want to create a type of banner or does it need to propagate a custom page automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible with a widget (catalog category link), it also knows the name of the category used , however, i have NO idea how to fit the category pic in there.

Comment: Yeah, me to :) Best way would be to insert a link field next to image upload. Currently there is no point of having category image if you can't link it.